# DFP not render true winner

Tags: google-dfp, prebid.js, criteo, header-bidding

[image: prebid1]
[image: prebid2]
I am new in DFP and Header bidding. I ready setup complete Header bidding with DFP now, but i have a problem: DFP not render true ads

From image prebid1, I can seen Criteo and RTBHouse is bidder response, and Criteo is choose, but in below RTBHouse is render.

From image prebid2, I can seen RTBHouse line item is choose.

I hope someone can help me, or any sugguest tool for me check what happen. I use prebid 2.20.0

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a little more detail as to how your header bidding price buckets are setup and what are their targeting criteria?